# Cell value from offset range

Tags: vba, excel

```
yellow_cell = ActiveCell.Address
MsgBox (Range(yellow_cell).Value)
implant = yellow_cell.Offset(6, -2).Address
MsgBox (Range(implant).Value)
```

The first `MsgBox` works, but the second one doesn't (Run-time error 424, object required).

I've also tried this:

```
implant = ActiveCell.Offset(6, -2).Address
MsgBox (Range(implant).Value)
```

And I get a run-time error 1004, Method 'Offset' of object 'Range' failed.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've unmerged all cells btw.

Comment: .Address returns a string not a Range so it does not implement .Offset() - Is there a reason for using Address at all?  ActiveCell *is* the cell (Range) of interest.

Comment: @Sgdva You were so right. It's going off the page. Amazing help, I was tearing my hair out for half an hour trying to solve this. Thanks

Comment: @AlexK. He's doing it right, the range argument is receiving a string. 
Aren't you going off limits when you're doing the offset? IE: you are in column A or B and then applying offset -2, going off limits

Comment: @Sgdva - `yellow_cell.Offset(6, -2).Address` - this one causes the error 424. `yellow_cell` is a String, and not an Object.

Comment: You're right, I missed that it should be `Range(yellow_cell).Offset(6, -2)...` although I agree, the best approach is to save it directly as range, no need for the address in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the proper way to achieve the desired results:

```
Dim implant As Range, yellow_cell As Range

Set yellow_cell = ActiveCell
MsgBox yellow_cell.Value
Set implant = yellow_cell.Offset(6, -2)
MsgBox implant.Value
```

**Notice**: If the active cell is less than two columns away from column A, then this code will result in `run-time error 1004`, due to the second parameter of the `Offset` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is to test whether the column is in fact further right than 2 columns, something like below, this shouldn't cause any errors:

```
Sub foo()

Dim yellow_cell As String, implant As String
Dim col As Long

yellow_cell = ActiveCell.Address
MsgBox (Range(yellow_cell).Value)
col = ActiveCell.Column

If col > 2 Then
    implant = ActiveCell.Offset(6, -2).Address
    MsgBox (Range(implant).Value)
Else
    MsgBox "Out of Range!", vbInformation, "Error"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not true in all scenarios: if I do it on column "C" for example, why couldn't `col` be less than 2?

Comment: @Sgdva Because `col - 2` would be zero or negative, which is not a valid column reference. What Xabier is saying in the code is that the col number must be at least 3, which is correct when you're offsetting by -2.

Comment: @Sgdva If you try the code I posted with the ActiveCell being on Column C, you will see that it works as expected, but if the ActiveCell is in fact in column A or B, then you will be notified that it is out of Range, instead of getting an error.